# how to add multiple variables from vector and assign it to zero in R

Tags: r

I have vector of strings

```
 vec <- ("Name","Address","Age")
```

I have a following dataframe

```
 ID    ColumnA     ColumnB
 1       AVF         ERT
 2       WER         TYU
```

I want to add new columns basis the vectors and assign the value zero to them
My desired dataframe would look like following

```
ID    ColumnA     ColumnB    Name    Address   Age
 1       AVF         ERT      0        0        0
 2       WER         TYU      0        0        0
```

How can I do it in R ?

Comment: `DF[, vec] <- 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column from a string using `df[, "somestring"] <-`.  I'm not aware of a way to do it with the `$` operator although there may be one.

```
vec <- c("Name","Address","Age")
df <- data.frame(something = rep("stuff",2))
df[,vec[1]] <- 0

> df
  something Name
1     stuff    0
2     stuff    0
```

etc

Comment: Code only answers may provide the answer to the problem, but an explanation helps a lot in understanding what you've changed and why it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm new to answering questions, trying to give a little back after years of reading others answers!